# billmelater integration / api documentation? sandbox account?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-nvp

I would like to find the Paypal BillMeLater documentation. I've looked over the developer site many times and searched all over Google; where might it be?

Also - where can I create a sandbox account for testing payments processed via BillMeLater?

To be clear, I would like to integrate BillMeLater so that a user is not redirected away from the site, but can still use this method to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible; BillMeLater can only be used via the paypal site (eg: through express checkout)